# Wrong time and date when I use new Date() mongoose and nodejs 10

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

So I have a mongoose schema with some of the property types set to Date. But there is an issue when I save some values to the database, the date seems either to be one day behind ( and wrong timezone), or just completely wrong. Below is part of the schema

```
dob: {
    type: Date,
    required: [
        true,
        "Date of birth is required"
    ]
}
```

So, when I save a date like : 12-June-1993, I get this : 1993-06-11T22:00:00.000Z

The date is a day behind, and I don't really know what is causing this.
Using NodeJS 10, Mongoose 5.0.17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is perfectly fine. When you are storing date as '12-June-1993' you are not providing a time zone or its not in ISO format so it takes it as a Locale date time stamp meaning its taking as your (your servers) Time zone date. But its stored as ISO date time stamp (GMT/UTC) and as a result its standardized.

Now when reading the date time if you print the date as a locale string you will see the time as '12-June-1993'.

> let date = new Date('1993-06-11T22:00:00.000Z');
>
> date.toLocaleString() // 6/12/1993, 3:00:00 AM